# How to update only selected values in a 2 dimensional list without using for loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, matrix, list-comprehension

I have a huge matrix with around 80000 rows and 66000 columns. I need to update selected values in each row. These selected values vary from row to row. For example, I might have to update 346th, 446th, 789th and 321th column values for first row and for second row I might have to update 821th, 564th, 101th, 781th column values. I hope you get the situation.

Here, I am simulating the problem using a small matrix.
Suppose I have a 2 dimensional list/matrix.

```
matrix = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

In the actual problem, I need to update all the rows but here for the sake of simplicity I am considering only 1 row. i.e. 2nd row. I wish to update 1st and 2nd values of 2nd row and keep the rest of the values in 2nd row as they are.
I need to do it without using for loops.
The code I tried is as follows :

```
index_list = [0,1]
matrix[1] = [ matrix[1][index] + 1 for index in index_list ]
print(matrix)
```

Here, index_list is the list of selected columns that need to be updated. The output I get is :

```
[[1, 2, 3], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

The output I need / expected output is :

```
[[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

So, the question is, I wish to update only 1sta and 2nd values of second row for above given matrix and keep the rest of the values in 2nd row as it is. And this needs to be done without using for loops because of time constraints. I am trying to use list compression because it is relatively fast. Could you please help with it ?
I forgot to mention the code is in python, and we can use pandas, numpy if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matrix[1] = [matrix[1][i] + 1 if i in index_list else matrix[1][i] for i in range(len(matrix[1]))]
```

This solution worked.

Comment: @Ramasamy Kandasamy   This solution has been derived by making small changes to answer suggested by Ramasamy Kandasamy

Answer (score 0):

You need to cover the case where the index is *not* in the list, preserving those values:

```
matrix[1] = [ matrix[1][index] + 1 if index in index_list
                                   else matrix[1][index] ]
```

Comment: I guess it is `matrix[1] = [matrix[1][index] + 1 if index in index_list else matrix[1][index] for i in range(len(matrix[1]))]`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. It gave the same output as I got and I mentioned above. Here, the problem is you have used else matrix[1][index] but this 'index' you are referring to is not in index_list. Index_list contains only those indexes which need to be updated.

Comment: @RamasamyKandasamy Your suggestion works with a few change as follows : 
`matrix[1] = [matrix[1][i] + 1 if i in index_list else matrix[1][i] for i in range(len(matrix[1]))]` 
Thanks